# How to dynamically translate the application

Tags: dart, flutter

I followed the steps [here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) to start the translation of my application. I used the .arb file method.

I understand the application get translated when changing the language of the OS, but is it possible, within the application, to toggle the language and make the application dynamically translated?

If so, what should I do? I tried to call the 'load' method, but nothing happened.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could use easy plugin to simplify this. [localize_and_translate](https://pub.dev/packages/localize_and_translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Locale` of `MaterialApp` and then when you want to change just call

```
  setState(() {
    _locale = Locale('b'); // Desired locale
  });
```

Below code changes `Locale` in every 5 seconds.

```
  Locale _locale;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _locale = Locale('a');
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (t) {
      setState(() {
        _locale = _locale == Locale('a') ? Locale('b') : Locale('a');
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('a'),
        const Locale('b'),
        const Locale('c'),
      ],
      localizationsDelegates: [
        MaterialLocalizationDelegateKa(),
        const InfosLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: _locale,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Tomike Qurdadze, I tried your example and it worked. But when I tried to change the locale variable inside another page/class, it did not even if I put the locale variable as global. I think I need to introduce inheritedwidget somehwere, right? What do you think?

Comment: After changing Locale you have to rebuild parent MaterialApp.